# I am getting following error while running diaspora pod (ruby application) deployed on ubuntu14.04 system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, diaspora

I am getting following error while running diaspora pod (ruby application) deployed on ubuntu14.04 system

bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8@diaspora/bin/unicorn)

ubuntu@ip:~/diaspora$ ./script/server
WARNING: Setting port via configuration is deprecated, set listen instead. See the updated config/diaspora.yml.example.
Starting Diaspora in development mode on port 3000 with job processing inside the request cycle.

I, [2016-06-30T18:31:18.139991 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:**default**] send_command: monitor
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:18.142457 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:**default**] schedule :monitor (reason: monitor by user)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:18.142780 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:**default**] => monitor  (reason: monitor by user)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:18.142940 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:**default**] starting async with 0.2s chain monitor []
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:18.143217 #1580]  INFO -- : [Eye] <= loading: ["/home/ubuntu/diaspora/config/eye.rb"]
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:18.157191 #1580]  INFO -- : [Eye] <= command: load /home/ubuntu/diaspora/config/eye.rb (0.181545199s)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:18.158367 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] schedule :monitor (reason: monitor by user)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:18.158632 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] => monitor  (reason: monitor by user)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:18.158705 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:**default**] <= monitor
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:18.159647 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] pid_file not found, starting...
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:18.160052 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] switch :starting [:unmonitored => :starting] (reason: monitor by user)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:18.161873 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] daemonizing: `bin/bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb` with start_grace: 2.5s, env: 'DB=mysql RAILS_ENV=development PORT=3000', <1720> (in /home/ubuntu/diaspora)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:18.162008 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] sleeping for :start_grace 2.5
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:20.662786 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] switch :started [:starting => :up] (reason: monitor by user)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:20.665149 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] <= monitor
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8@diaspora/bin/unicorn)
W, [2016-06-30T18:31:25.663536 #1580]  WARN -- : [diaspora:web] check_alive: process <1720> not found
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:25.663809 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] delete pid_file: /home/ubuntu/diaspora/tmp/pids/web.pid
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:25.664177 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] switch :crashed [:up => :down] (reason: crashed)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:25.664615 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] schedule :check_crash (reason: crashed)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:25.665000 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] => check_crash  (reason: crashed)
W, [2016-06-30T18:31:25.665108 #1580]  WARN -- : [diaspora:web] check crashed: process is down
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:25.665185 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] schedule :restore (reason: crashed)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:25.665359 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] <= check_crash
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:25.665547 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] => restore  (reason: crashed)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:25.665635 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] pid_file not found, starting...
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:25.665866 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] switch :starting [:down => :starting] (reason: crashed)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:25.667339 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] daemonizing: `bin/bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb` with start_grace: 2.5s, env: 'DB=mysql RAILS_ENV=development PORT=3000', <1725> (in /home/ubuntu/diaspora)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:25.667438 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] sleeping for :start_grace 2.5
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:28.168226 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] switch :started [:starting => :up] (reason: crashed)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:28.170467 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] <= restore
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8@diaspora/bin/unicorn)
W, [2016-06-30T18:31:33.168931 #1580]  WARN -- : [diaspora:web] check_alive: process <1725> not found
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:33.169188 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] delete pid_file: /home/ubuntu/diaspora/tmp/pids/web.pid
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:33.169547 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] switch :crashed [:up => :down] (reason: crashed)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:33.170001 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] schedule :check_crash (reason: crashed)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:33.170419 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] => check_crash  (reason: crashed)
W, [2016-06-30T18:31:33.170527 #1580]  WARN -- : [diaspora:web] check crashed: process is down
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:33.170602 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] schedule :restore (reason: crashed)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:33.170781 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] <= check_crash
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:33.170977 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] => restore  (reason: crashed)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:33.171062 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] pid_file not found, starting...
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:33.171282 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] switch :starting [:down => :starting] (reason: crashed)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:33.172718 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] daemonizing: `bin/bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb` with start_grace: 2.5s, env: 'DB=mysql RAILS_ENV=development PORT=3000', <1730> (in /home/ubuntu/diaspora)
I, [2016-06-30T18:31:33.172822 #1580]  INFO -- : [diaspora:web] sleeping for :start_grace 2.5

Comment: Can you post which command you ran?

Comment: Hi after following diaspora Ubuntu14.04 installation page (https://wiki.diasporafoundation.org/Installation/Ubuntu/Trusty?db=mysql&mode=development)

I ran "./script/server" command to start diaspora.

Answer (score 1):

Change [line 172 or around there in diaspora.yml](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/blob/develop/config/diaspora.yml.example#L172)

```
#rails_environment: 'development'
```

to 'production' and uncomment it.

Comment: thanks for replying.. after doing above changes and then on trying to run Diaspora Pod its still not running the application properly..

Comment: E, [2016-07-04T13:57:26.975262 #1639] ERROR -- : [diaspora:web] process <1781> not found, it may have crashed (you should check the process logs ["/home/ubuntu/diaspora/log/eye_processes_stdout.log", "/home/ubuntu/diaspora/log/eye_processes_stderr.log"])
E, [2016-07-04T13:57:26.975436 #1639] ERROR -- : [diaspora:web] process <1781> failed to start (:not_really_running)

Comment: Can you edit your question with the full log including the command you ran? Also it would help if you could highlight your entire log and then click the code {} formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Setting port via configuration is deprecated, set listen instead

There's your problem right there. You need to manually compare your config/diaspora.yml file to the updated config/diaspora.yml.examle file, using a tool like meld.

they changed the line that specifies the port setting, it should now say something like:

```
listen: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/'
```

this is line 178 in the latest template...